# Special character not showing in correct font

Tags: html, character

So I've downloaded a font from Fontsquirrel which has all the letters used in Estonian language. It works fine in the browser when I use all the common letters, but as soon as I use the letter "ž", it's not displaying the correct font.

This is how my HTML looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>8 Delfiini | Massaažiga argipäevast kõrgemale</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> <!--page wrapper-->
<section id="avaleht">
  <h1>Massaažiga argipäevast kõrgemale</h1>
</section>
...
```

And the CSS:

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'alluraregular';
    font-size: 6em;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

I changed the "lang=en" to "lang=et", but it didn't work.

This is the result:

[image: Capture]

Is there a way to make this work properly? Thank you!

Comment: Can you point me to the font?  It's possible that character is stored in a different location in the font file.

Comment: I hope I understood correctly. :) Fontface looks like this:

Comment: @font-face {
    font-family: 'alluraregular';
    src:url('../fonts/allura-regular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/allura-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/allura-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/allura-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/allura-regular-webfont.svg#alluraregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

The link to the Fontsquirel is here: http://bit.ly/1k4ZMCg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FontSquirrel webfont generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) by default uses “Basic subsetting” for “Western languages”, which effectively means ISO Latin 1, designed for languages of Western and Northern Europe, lacking e.g. ž, z with caron. To overcome this, select “Expert” in the user interface, then either “No subsetting” or “Custom subsetting” with suitable options (either “Latin Extended-A” or “Estonian” should handle the issue). Since the font is small, “No subsetting” is the best option.